# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for a 2D array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a program that generates chutes and ladders onto 2D array board that is of size 10X10. In order to generate these chutes and ladders, I had to create a method called `readBoard` that basically reads a written file (myBoard.csv) and translates the written information into positions and place the chutes and ladders onto the 2D array board accordingly.

The program compiles but when I run it there is this error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ChutesAndLadders.readBoard(ChutesAndLadders.java:41)
    at TestFile.main(TestFile.java:13)`
 
My impression was that perhaps my written file had additional spaces that I didn't see that's why it's telling me I'm out of bound. However, I checked the written file and it looks fine. If you could provide some insight into this problem, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Here is my `getBoard`method:

```
public void readBoard(String filename)throws Exception 
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(new File(filename));
    s.nextInt();
    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        String line=s.nextLine();
        String[]singleSplit=line.split(",");
        String cellType=singleSplit[0];
        int row=Integer.parseInt(singleSplit[1]);
        int col=Integer.parseInt(singleSplit[2]);
        if (cellType.equals("Chute"))
            board[row][col]=new Chute();
        else
            board[row][col]=new Ladder();
    }
}
```

and here is my written file (type,row,column):

29

Chute,1,0

Chute,2,0

Chute,3,0

Chute,4,0

Chute,5,0

Chute,6,0

Chute,7,0

Chute,8,0

Chute,9,0

Chute,0,1

Chute,0,2

Chute,0,3

Chute,9,1

Chute,9,2

Chute,9,3

Ladder,0,5

Ladder,1,5

Ladder,2,5

Ladder,3,5

Ladder,4,5

Ladder,5,5

Ladder,6,5

Ladder,7,5

Ladder,8,5

Ladder,9,5

Ladder,9,6

Ladder,9,7

Ladder,9,8

Ladder,9,9

Comment: What is the 29 doing in your file?

Comment: is your board initialized?

Comment: That is the number of the listed items on the file.

Comment: Also, can we see your board 2d array declaration ? is it board[10][10].

Comment: Yes I initialized by board.

Comment: `That is the number of the listed items on the file.` - so what is returned when you invoke nextLine() for the first time? Did you display the contents of the "line" variable? A basic debugging technique is to display the value in the variable when you have a problem to see if the variable contains what you think it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `s.nextInt();` with `s.nextLine();` to read the first line from the file. If you need that value, you can do `Integer.parseInt()` on it.

Comment: I tested it and made the change that you recommended. I got the exact output that I was looking for. Thanks for spotting that mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt()` doesn't change the line counter in `Scanner`, so `nextLine()` call will return the rest of the line you're currently at. To avoid that you need to explicitly change line counter by doing an extra `nextLine()` call after your `nextInt()`:

```
s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

From [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) API doc:

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>   separator at the end.

So in your code the first call to `nextLine()` simply returns an empty string.

Comment: Hey thanks for providing an answer. You were right. That' all I had to do was to change that line. Thanks for the help.